# How to remove binary content from the strings?

Tags: string, go, id3

I was trying to read ID3 tags from mp3 files using golang.
I get the results. But they also contain some binary content as my [database viewer](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qcp3vww66tkyycp/Screenshot%20from%202015-11-07%2009-28-17.png?dl=0) suggests.

[image: picture]

Any way to remove that content in golang?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a current issue in [id3-go](https://github.com/mikkyang/id3-go): [PR 8](https://github.com/mikkyang/id3-go/pull/8) fixes it for id3v1

But that isn't enough for id3v2, as show [in this commit](https://github.com/frodeaa/dircast/commit/894cfe7a1bd18fbc341b35471befc0f5b7f52173), which does have to trim those null characters.
See the use of `cutset := string(rune(0))`, and of [`TrimRight(s string, cutset string)`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#TrimRight), as in for instance `strings.TrimRight(fd.Title(), cutset)`:

```
fd, err := id3.Open(path)
if err != nil {
    item.Title = f.Name()
} else {
    defer fd.Close()
    cutset := string(rune(0))
    title := strings.TrimRight(fd.Title(), cutset)
    author := strings.TrimRight(fd.Artist(), cutset)
    if len(title) > 0 {
        item.Title = title
    } else {
        item.Title = author
        if len(author) > 0 {
            item.Title += " - "
        }
        item.Title += strings.TrimRight(f.Name(), cutset)
    }
    item.Subtitle = author
    tcon := fd.Frame("TCON")
    if tcon != nil {
        item.Categories = append(item.Categories, Text{Value: strings.TrimRight(tcon.String(), cutset)})
    }
    item.PubDate = strings.TrimRight(formatYear(fd.Year()), cutset)
```

Comment: Yeah, That worked for me....... Sometimes the data is Filled with U's... I'll figure out something